# C implement solution Sudoku with brute Force doesn't work

Tags: c

I wrote code to implement brute force in C but doesn't run.

I've tried to debug it but I got a debugger infinity loop, I need help!

```c
int bruteForce(s_cellBoard board[9][9], int i, int arr_32[]) {
    if (i == 81 || i < 0)
        return 1;
    //if he put number in cell
    if (isPossible(board, i, arr_32))
    {//check cell that is not givan- can change
        do { i++; } while (board[i / 9][i % 9].isGiven);
    }
    else
    {
        board[i / 9][i % 9].value = 0;
        //check cell tht is not givan- can change
        do { i--; } while (board[i / 9][i % 9].isGiven);
    }
    return  bruteForce(board, i, arr_32);
}
```

this function if can put number in cell

```c
int isPossible(s_cellBoard board[9][9], int i, int arr_32[])
{
    int num = board[i / 9][i % 9].value ? board[i / 9][i % 9].value+1 : 1;
    for (; num <= 9 && (!row(board, i, num) || !col(board, i, num) || !block(board, i, num));num++);
    if (num<= 9)
    {
        board[i / 9][i % 9].value = num;
        printf("%d\n", board[i / 9][i % 9].value);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

the function call to bruteForce

```c
int f_solveSudoku(s_cellBoard board[9][9])
{
    int arr_32[513] = { 0 };
    initialization32Arr(arr_32);
    int i = 0;
    while (board[i / 9][i % 9].isGiven) { i++; }
    return bruteForce(board, i, arr_32);
}
```

functions to check the block

```
int block(s_cellBoard board[9][9], int i, int num) {
    for (int b, a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < 3; b++)
        {
            if (board[((i / 9) - ((i / 9) % 3)) + a][((i % 9) - ((i % 9) % 3)) + b].value == num)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

functions to check the column

```
int col(s_cellBoard board[9][9], int i, int num) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        if (board[j][i % 9].value == num)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

functions to check the row

```
int row(s_cellBoard board[9][9], int i, int num) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        if (board[i / 9][j].value == num)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It is possible for `i` to go out of range in those `do ... while` loops, so you should check for that: `do { i++; } while (i < 81 && board[i / 9][i % 9].isGiven;` and `do { i--; } while (i >= 0 && board[i / 9][i % 9].isGiven;`.

Comment: How do you keep track of which digits have been tried in each position?

Comment: I guess `bruteForce` is initially called from `main` with the `i` parameter set to 0. In that case, if `board[0][0].isGiven` is true, the `isPossible` function will be called on a "given" cell. That looks like a bug.

Comment: After `isPossible` returns false, `bruteForce` back-tracks, but there doesn't seem to be anything in your code to prevent it starting with exactly the same digit that it started with last time, so it will never progress towards a solution.

Comment: int num = board[i / 9][i % 9].value ? board[i / 9][i % 9].value+1 : 1; put in the num this value+1 so it start with next digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modification to the `bruteForce` function should work.  I'm not sure what the `arr_32[]` parameter is for, as it does not seem to be used.

```
int bruteForce(s_cellBoard board[9][9], int i, int arr_32[]) {
    // skip cells with 'given' numbers
    while (i < 81 && board[i / 9][i % 9].isGiven)
        i++;
    if (i == 81)
        return 1; // done all the cells, so solution found
    // check numbers 1 to 9 for current cell
    while (isPossible(board, i, arr_32))
    {
        // found a possible number for the cell
        // so check remaining cells
        if (bruteForce(board, i + 1, arr_32))
            return 1; // solution found
    }
    // tried all the numbers for this cell without finding a solution
    board[i / 9][i % 9].value = 0; // reset the cell
    return 0; // solution not yet found
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still this is an endless loop

Comment: @user11674988 It worked for me. It might take a long time to complete if your `row()`, `col()` and `board()` functions are wrong. Can you show the code for those functions in your question?

Comment: @user11674988 I've corrected the name of the `isGiven` member to match your code, but that's all I've changed since your comment above.